# With iron-ajax, how to read the headers of a response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

When a response for a request arrives, is there any way to read the response headers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The response event handlers gets passed the `<iron-request>` as the second argument. `<iron-request>` has an [`xhr` property](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/v1.0.1/iron-request.html#L34-L41) that is the `XMLHttpRequest` used to make the request. You should be able to get the response headers from that.

```
<iron-ajax on-response="ajaxResponse"></iron-ajax>
...
ajaxResponse: function(e, request) {
  var headers = request.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If an HTTP request is made over AJAX in javascript, it is possible to get the response headers with the getAllResponseHeaders() method. It's part of the XMLHttpRequest API.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed the iron-ajax part of question.

```
<iron-ajax
    url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
    params='{"alt":"json", "q":"chrome"}'
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>
    ...
handleResponse: function(e, request) {
    var headers = request.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
    alert(headers)
  }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: As a follow up question, how would one determine the ***method*** that was used for the request?  I can get the ***xhr.responseURL***, but I don't see where I can determine which method was used for the call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Trevor Dixon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795765/2073920), `iron-ajax` provides `iron-request` object in response handler which exposes `XMLHttpRequest` as `xhr` property.

A specific response header can be obtained using [getResponseHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader) method of `XMLHttpRequest`.

> ironRequest.xhr.getResponseHeader('header name');

All headers can be obtained using [getAllResponseHeaders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders) method of `XMLHttpRequest` which is rarely used since we mostly don't want to read all headers at once.